# How to solve for $k$ in integral? (hypothesis testing)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, negative-binomial-distribution, integral

In a hypothesis testing problem I am stuck at this step, trying to solve for $k$ in the relation:

$$F_{NegBin(n,0.5)}(k)=0.05$$

The problem is no matter which cumulative distribution function I relate this with, it is always an integral. So how do I solve for $k$? For example, using the fact that

$$F_{NegBin(n,0.5)}(k)=1-\frac{B(0.5;k+1,n)}{B(k+1,n)}=0.05,$$

in the numerator we have the integral

$$\int_0^{0.5}t^{k+2}(1-t)^{n-1}dt$$

How do I solve this for $k$? Do I even need to solve for $k$ to use a most powerful test?

Comment: This search (on what is perhaps a surprising set of keywords) will point you towards effective algorithms: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=inverse+incomplete+beta+function

Comment: And if you use R, try `?qbeta`

Comment: @whuber I meant theoretically, but are we not there yet?

Comment: Theoretically, the answer is to apply the inverse of the normalized incomplete Beta function.